# Bash: How to return from parent function if child function failed?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to clean up some of my code, for that I want to clean the check return code status check I make after each command. If the command fails I return mid function to the parent function. 
If I'll take this code inside a function then nothing happens as the return command will be inside the new-child function.

Sure gald for some thoughts.

Current status:

```
a(){
    for i in $(cat file.txt)
    do
        scp $i hostb:/tmp/

        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
        then
            print_failed "SCP failed."
            return 1
        fi
    done
}
```

Desired:

```
a(){
    for i in $(cat file.txt)
    do
        scp $i hostb:/tmp/

        # continue as usuall unless return code is not 0
        check_status $?
    done
}

check_status(){
    if [ $1 -ne 0 ]
    then
        print_failed "SCP failed."
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, there is no *implicit* way to return from the parent function if the child function failed.

The closest thing I can think of would be something like this:

```
a () {
    while read -r source    # don't read lines with "for"!
    do
        check_status scp "$source" hostb:/tmp/ || return 1
    done < file.txt
}

check_status () {
    if ! "$@"
    then
        print_failed "SCP failed."
        return 1
    fi
}
```

The role of `check_status` is to execute a command and print the failure message if it didn't succeed. It also returns `1`, so the parent function can use `if !` or `||` to return as well.

There's no way of returning from the parent function except by using global variables, which I would personally avoid if possible.

To be honest though, I don't see the advantage of what you have over this:

```
a () {
    while read -r source
    do
        if ! scp "$source" hostb:/tmp/
        then
            print_failed "SCP failed."
            return 1
        fi
    done < file.txt
}
```

Comment: The idea behinds it, it's all above code readness.. If there is still `if` in the parent function that check the return code, then it is not much different from the original code..

Comment: You _could_ use `exit` instead of `return` but that would kill the whole script - is that what you want?

Comment: Can't use `exit`.

Comment: I edited to show a shorthand in the parent function but I think the simple answer to your original question is "no, it's not possible".

Comment: That's also an answer :)